# How to normalize input data to Reinforcement learning platform (Gym and stable-baselines)

Tags: neural-networks, reinforcement-learning, deep-learning, gym, stable-baselines

I created a custom environment with Gym and trained it with stable baseline 3 algorithms.
The observation and space action are both continues.
The observation space includes 10 values and action space has 2.
The action space is [0,1] and I know it's not symmetric.

I want to normalize my inputs to the NN and I Don't Know how to do it.
The environment observes Temperature and Power (input values) and takes action (continuous between [0,1]) and returns state (10 values not normalized)
I believe I have to normalized all inputs to get better results but I don't know how can I normalize it bf feeding to neuronal network and unwrapped it afterwards.

I appreciate any help specially if you can link some dummy code or a practical case.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.